# Factor out certain terms using Modulus but Mathematica requires that the modulus be an integer

Tags: factorization

[image]

Mathematica demands that the modulus be an integer. How do I work my way around this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory Tour now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please insert the actual code in your question, not an image of it. Doing so will increase the chance of receiving good responses.

Comment: `ac` is **not** the product of a and c. You should write it as `a c` or as `a*c`. Note also that mathematica is case sensitive so `a c` does not equal `A C`. Please note also that all of Mathematica's built-in names start with an uppercase letter, even the one-letter ones (C, D, E, I, N, O). So it's good to start yours with lowercase letters in order to avoid conflicts.

Comment: What is the anticipated result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have re-labelled your image for convenience. In future, please refer to documentation re: posting code rather than images. I may have made some transcription errors but perhaps this will point you in direction you are aiming for.

```
e1 = a x^2 + c y^2 + b x y
e2 = 2 c y z + 2 a w x + 2 b (x z + y w)
e3 = a w^2 + c z^2 + b w z
Factor[PolynomialMod[Expand[e2^2 - 4 e1 e3], 4 a c - b^2]]
```

yielding: 4 (w y + x z) (a b w x + 3 a c w y + 3 a c x z + b c y z)

Comment: 1+ For volunteering, call for code ... and code